.net 8 azure function (http trigger) is returning empty object though object has value
I have written a very simple azure http trigger function and that is returning an object but in postman response I am getting empty object. Trigger response type is IActionResult and I am returning as "new OkObjectResult(list);". This is very strange issue. in .net 6 it's working but it's not working in .net 8 version.
sample code has given below.
[Function("Function")]
public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>()
    {
        new MyClass()
        {
            Name="abc"
        }
    };
  return  new OkObjectResult(list);
    
}

Postman response:

Csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
     </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


Look for any common problems with Azure Functions and .NET 8, especially about turning objects into JSON or how HTTP triggers work. New versions can sometimes have new bugs or changes, which you can find mentioned in the update notes or by what people are saying online.

I am able to get the expected output. Can you share the .csproj file

I have added csproj file. pls have a look . thank you in advance for your response.

This is a worker function. "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"

Show us the definition of MyClass; maybe we will find that Name is a field, not a property, and you're using serializer settings that do not serialize fields

I'm having the same problem currently. We recently upgraded to dotnet8 isolated worker, and our response body is like an empty wireframe of the object. In debug, on a breakpoint I can still see that object has values while inside the the return new OkObjectResult and seconds later in postman the values are missing.
Additonally, you may want to add a tag to your question specifying isolated worker

I believe you and I have the same issue, and I have discovered a little more about it. It seems like the underlying serializer used by OkObjectResult's constructor (and other IActionResults/HttpDataResponses) does not work the way it used to. I can confirm that JObject's and JContainer's return skeleton's when passed to new OkObjectResult()
Here is some sample code I generated to prove the point. This was not an issue in dotnet 6.
    public class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        var myPoco = new MyPoco()
        {
            Id = "abc",
            Type = "noneYet",
            MyData = new { foo = "bar", bar = new { foob = "ar", count = -1 } }
        };
        //OPTION 1 works in both dotnet 6 and 8
        //myPoco.Type = myPoco.MyData.GetType().BaseType.Name; // will be Object
        //return new OkObjectResult(myPoco); //will return full properties of MyData
        
        //OPTION 2 works in dotnet 6, fails in dotnet 8
        var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myPoco);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyPoco>(serialized);
        deserialized.Type = deserialized.MyData.GetType().BaseType.Name; // will be JContainer
        return new OkObjectResult(deserialized); //will return skeleton of myData in dotnet 8
    }
}

[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class MyPoco
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public object MyData { get; set; }
}

I found a workaround for this, though I wish there was a better way. Instead of returning an OkObjectResult, the following should solve your problem the same way it solved mine:
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myPoco),
            ContentType = "application/json", 
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK
        };



Create the new azure function app project

Function.cs code:


    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
    using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    namespace FunctionApp3
    {
        public class MyClass
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
    
        public static class Function
        {
            [FunctionName("Function")]
            public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req, ILogger _logger)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
                List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>()
        {
            new MyClass()
            {
                Name="abc"
            }
        };
                return new OkObjectResult(list);
    
            }
        } 
    }


Csproj file:

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>


